# Configure selected allow group to access HTTPD url

Tags: apache, active-directory

I have setup Apache HTTPD to perform reverse proxy to a web server hosting Tomcat. I wanted to allow 2 AD's groups to be able to access the url:8443, group1 and group2. 
When i tried to access the URL using the user from group1, everything works fine as I am able to access the tomcat URL. But when I tried to access the URL using the user from group2, it fails, it prompt for the basic authentication where I have to enter the username and password. I would like to check on how can I also apply users from group2 to access the URL.

I tried to reverse by putting group2 on top of group1, and I am not able to access the tomcat URL when I am using group1's user.

Here is my configuration in the httpd.conf

```
    <VirtualHost *:8443>
        AllowOverride None
        Options None
        AuthName "Test"
        AuthType SSPI
        SSPIAuth On
        SSPIAuthoritative On
        SSPIDomain TESTDOMAIN
        <RequireAll>
            <RequireAny>
                require sspi-group TESTDOMAIN\group1
                require sspi-group TESTDOMAIN\group2
            </RequireAny>
            <RequireNone>
                Require user "ANONYMOUS LOGON"
                Require user "NT-AUTORITÃ„T\ANONYMOUS-ANMELDUNG"
            </RequireNone>
        </RequireAll>
    </VirtualHost>
```

Answer (score 0):

check below url which might help you to configure httpd further as per your requirement

https://www.jamescoyle.net/how-to/1410-apache-active-directory-group-authentication

also do not forget to install and activate module LDAP in HTTPD.

also do check below official url for the same

https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_authnz_ldap.html